# Word for 'No Facial Expression'

Tags: single-word-requests

> As she turned to leave, the flower retailer immediately replaced his
>   smile with ...

I want to say he replaced his smile with his 'idle face' or his face without expression, but neither of those sound good.

The face that you pull when you're not pulling a face. Not a defined expression. Kinda like I've noticed I'm doing right now as I type (though this fact's no help to answerers).

Comment: You could also write “the smile immediately faded from the florist's face.”

Comment: He kept a straight face.

Comment: Try "blank", "bland" or maybe "keanu".

Comment: **poker face** :|

Answer (score 14):

The most common phrase would be 'blank', thus:

> As she turned to leave, the flower seller immediately replaced his smile with a blank expression.

(No one says 'retailer' outside of industry magazines).

Comment: The British vernacular would be “blank **look**.

Answer (score 11):

I like @[ElendilTheTall's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/131860/191178), but here are a few alternatives.

If you're trying to emphasize the transition from smiling to neutral, you could say something like

> As she turned to leave, the smile faded from the florist's face.

If the smile was put on or phony, you could say

> As she turned to leave, the florist immediately dropped his smile.

If you're trying to emphasize the new, inscrutable expression, one option is [poker face](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poker%20face), "an expression on your face that does not show your thoughts or feelings".

> As she turned to leave, the florist immediately switched on his best poker face.

Answer (score 4):

I have used a few times [expressionless](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/expressionless?q=expressionless):

> He had an expressionless face, what was he really thinking.

Lacking expression:

> Their faces remained expressionless as they listened to the bad news.

Comment: ...immediately replaced his smile with an expressionless mask.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

instead of 'flower seller', I'd say florist--which is a flower seller.

blank expression can also be a staid expression

Answer (score 1):

I would go for *[bland](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/bland) expression*:

> 3 : showing no emotion, concern, etc.
>   ▪ a bland expression/face ▪

Alternatives are *[stony](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stony) expression* and *[poker face](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poker+face)*. The latter, however, implies someone actively trying to block expression from their face, not necessarily the true absence of emotion.

Comment: Similar to a stony expression, you could also say that he went ***stone-faced*** (or ***stony-faced***, an alternative form of the same word).

Comment: +1 for *stony*: As she turned to leave, the florist's face turned stony.  Or *lost all expression*

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'deadpan demeanour', but it does imply that the lack of expression is deliberate. Otherwise 'expressionless' is perhaps the best word.

Comment: Whenever someone uses deadpan, I always assume it's a blank expression to mask another one... Like when your telling a joke, the real comedians will remain deadpan instead of laughing or smiling with the joke

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is the word *inscrutable*, although I realize an inscrutable expression could be characterized as mysterious, impenetrable, hard to read.  Still, it's a good word if the person who is looking at the florist sees the expression but does not know how to interpret it.

What complicates things is that you give no reason why the flower seller lost his smile.  What did the customer(?) do or say to make the smile disappear.  Furthermore, why--if that is the case--is it significant for plot development?

Answer (score 0):

[Impassive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impassive), If you want to say it in a formal way.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Poker face would be the right noun, but I would say,

> ...the florist dropped his smile

or

> ...a vacant expression replaced the florist's smile

Answer (score -1):

1) Poker-Face
2) Stoic
3) Straight face
4) Blank

Comment: Two of those have already been included in other answers. Please add descriptions and links for the other two. I might also add that ‘straight face’ seems somewhat ill-suited here, as it refers specifically to holding back and concealing the desire to laugh.

Comment: Sorry, just joined the website. Have been acquainting myself with the portal.

Answer (score -3):

The psychologist's expression for a lack of facial expression is "flat affect"

References: http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=26293 & http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-a-flat-affect.htm

Comment: I added some references, but I feel "flat affect" is too extreme for the current situation.